# Calling multiple bash scripts and running them in parallel, not in sequence

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, parallelism

Suppose that I have three (or more) bash scripts: `script1.sh`, `script2.sh`, and `script3.sh`.  I would like to call all three of these scripts and run them in *parallel*.  One way to do this is to just execute the following commands:

```
nohup bash script1.sh &
nohup bash script2.sh &
nohup bash script3.sh &
```

(In general, the scripts may take several hours or days to finish, so I would like to use `nohup` so that they continue running even if my console closes.)

But, is there any way to execute those three commands in *parallel* with a *single* call?

I was thinking something like

```
nohup bash script{1..3}.sh &
```

but this appears to execute `script1.sh`, `script2.sh`, and `script3.sh` in sequence, not in parallel.

Comment: What does "single call" mean?

Comment: What is the use case? Do you have a million scripts to start?

Comment: @jw013 I mean, something like a single short line command.  If I have 100 scripts to start, I would like to be able to type something short (like `nohup bash script{1..100}.sh &` or `for i in {1..100}; do nohup bash script{1..100} &; done`), rather than typing `nohup bash script*.sh &` 100 different times.

Comment: In case the scripts have useful output: You can start them within `screen`, too (or `tmux`), in order to solve the console problem but keep access to the output (and input).

Comment: @l0b0 I have on the order of 100 scripts to start.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from typing all 3 of those commands in the same line. `nohup ... & nohup ... & nohup ... &`. If you mean instead that you want to run all of the scripts without typing each script name individually, a simple loop will do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
for((i=1;i<100;i++)); do nohup bash script${i}.sh & done
```

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis.

Comment: @HaukeLaging What if script names are different ?

Answer (score 17):

A better way would be to use [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). GNU parallel is simple and with it we can control the number of jobs to run in parallel with more control over the jobs.

In the below command, `script{1..3}.sh` gets expanded and are sent as arguments to `bash` in parallel. Here `-j0` indicates that as many jobs should be run as possible. By default `parallel` runs one job for one cpu core.

```
$ parallel -j0 bash :::: <(ls script{1..3}.sh)
```

And you can also try using

```
$ parallel -j0 bash ::: script{1..3}.sh
```

While executing the second method if you get any error message then it means that `--tollef` option is set in `/etc/parallel/config` and that needs to be deleted and every thing will work fine.

You can read `GNU Parallels` man page [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) for more richer options.

And in case if your are running the jobs from a remote machine, better use [`screen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) so that the session does not gets closed due to network problems. `nohup` is not necessary, as recent versions of bash as coming with `huponexit` as `off` and this will prevent parent shell from sending `HUP` signal to its children during its exit. In case if its not unset do it with

```
$ shopt -u huponexit
```

Comment: If you are going to use `bash` as the shell `parallel -j0 bash :::: <(ls script{1..3}.sh)` can be reduced to `parallel -j0 bash :::: script{1..3}.sh`, no?

Comment: No its not, when '::::' is used with parallel it means that the argument is a file which contains commands to be executed and not the command itself. Here we are using process substitution to redirect the script names within a files descriptor.

Comment: Er.. in that case why not `parallel -j0 bash ::: script{1..3}.sh`?

Comment: It's `bash ::: script{1..3}.sh` being passed to `parallel`, not `::: script{1..3}.sh`. So this should first expand to  `parallel bash ::: script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh` by the shell and then `parallel` invocations of `bash script1.sh`, `bash script2.sh`, `bash script3.sh`. I tried it

Comment: I think you are confused, Check out the answer I have mentioned `::::` and not `:::`, both have different use. Read the `parallel` man page to understand more about them.

Comment: No I am not confused, all I am stating is that the OP's problem is better solved with `parallel -j0 bash ::: script{1..3}.sh` - this is better than the `::::` approach since it avoids the need for process substitution. Also [parsing ls output is ridden with pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Please check your first comment where it is mentioned as `parallel -j0 bash :::: script{1..3}.sh` (four colon). This is causing the confustion :) But yes we can used `parallel -j0 bash ::: script{1..3}.sh`  (three colon) and I will add that to the solution.

Comment: If you are a `screen` kind of guy, check out `--tmux` (version 20140722 or later) which will run each job in its own tmux window.

Answer (score 10):

We can also use `xargs` to run multiple script in parallel.

```
$ ls script{1..5}.sh|xargs -n 1 -P 0 bash
```

here each script is passed to bash as argument separately. `-P 0` indicates that the number of parallel process can be as much as possible. It is also safer that using bash default `job control feature` `(&)`.

Answer (score 5):

A single *line* solution:

```
$ nohup bash script1.sh & nohup bash script2.sh & nohup bash script3.sh &
```

Less facetiously, just use a wrapper script:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
script1.sh &
script2.sh &
script3.sh &
$ nohup script.sh &
```

Or loop over them:

```
for script in dir/*.sh
do
    nohup bash "$script" &
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to save yourself some typing effort

```
eval "nohup bash "script{1..3}.sh" &"
```

Or on second thoughts, maybe not

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting a much simpler utility I just wrote. It's currently called par, but will be renamed soon to either parl or pll, haven't decided yet.

https://github.com/k-bx/par

API is as simple as:

```
par "script1.sh" "script2.sh" "script3.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parallelshell

```
parallelshell "echo 1" "echo 2" "echo 3"
```

https://github.com/keithamus/parallelshell

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this tool: https://github.com/wagoodman/bashful

Say you have `mytasks.yaml` with

```
tasks:
    - name: A title for some tasks
      parallel-tasks:
        - cmd: ./script1.sh
        - cmd: ./script2.sh -x an-arg
        - cmd: ./script3.sh -y some-other-arg
```

And you run it like so:

```
nohup bashful run mytasks.yaml
```

Your scripts would be run in parallel with a vertical progress bar (+eta if you've run it before and the time is deterministic). You can tweak how many tasks you want to run in parallel if you start running more than just the given 3 here:

```
config:
    max-parallel-commands: 6
tasks:
    ...
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

Write all your commands to a parent script (parent_script.sh) which looks like the following:

```
bash script1.sh &
bash script2.sh &
bash script3.sh &
wait
```

Adding "wait" at the end of the your script will run it in parallel. Then submit the parent script with nohup.

```
nohup bash parent_script.sh
```