# here-document basename conflicts?

Tags: bash, scripting, variable, basename

I am using EOF to generate bash scripts that run the Rscripts. In the Rscript I used `basename` to specify the output file name.

When I use `EOF` to generate a list of bash scripts, I could not get `basename` to work. The error message is shown below.  I was still able to get the bash scripts generated but the `${AF}` turned into a blank in both places where it presented. Very strange!

I had the bash script tested and it is working so I know the problem is somewhere between `EOF` and `basename`.

How can I use `basename` with `EOF`? Or is there any alternative methods? Thank you.

```
for letter in {A..Z}
      do cat <<- EOF > batch_${letter}.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    module load R/3.5.1
    R_func="/home/dir/R_func"
    TREAT="/home/dir/POP"
    BASE="/home/dir/base"
    OUTPUT="/home/dir/tmp"

    for AF in ${BASE}/${letter}*.txt_step3; do
    Rscript ${R_func}P_tools.R \
    --ptool ${R_func}/P_tools_linux \
    --group ${AF} \
    --treat ${TREAT}/pop_exclude24dup \
    --out ${OUTPUT}/OUT_$(basename ${AF%%_txt_step3})_noregress \
    --binary-target F; done

    EOF
       done
```

This is the error message

> basename: missing operand Try 'basename --help' for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command substitutions like your `$(basename ...)` and variables are also expanded in here-documents if the delimiter is not quoted. You should escape the `$` from `$(basename ...)` and also any `$` inside it.

Corrected version of your script:

```
for letter in {A..Z}
        do cat <<- EOF > batch_${letter}.sh
                #!/bin/bash
                module load R/3.5.1
                R_func="/home/dir/R_func"
                TREAT="/home/dir/POP"
                BASE="/home/dir/base"
                OUTPUT="/home/dir/tmp"

                for letter in {A..Z} do {
                for AF in \${BASE}/${letter}*.txt_step3; do
                Rscript \${R_func}P_tools.R \
                --ptool \${R_func}/P_tools_linux \
                --group \${AF} \
                --treat \${TREAT}/pop_exclude24dup \
                --out \${OUTPUT}/OUT_\$(basename \${AF%%_txt_step3})_noregress \
                --binary-target F; done
                }
        EOF
done
```

That is actually indented by tabs; this stupid web interface is turning tabs into spaces, which will probably break `<<-` which in any POSIX shell is only stripping tabs, not spaces from before the EOF delimiter and the lines from the here-document.

Comment: I actually like your previous version better! haha! Thank you @unclebilly, it works very well and your explanation is great.

Comment: It's still wrong, the `$` from `R_func` should be quoted, too. Fixed now.

Comment: Yes, it was not fully corrected at the time but enough info was given so I learned from you that I needed to add the backsslah to variables. Thank you again. Very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The `<< EOF`...`EOF` construct is called a here-document, and you can put whatever string you like as the delimiter, but `EOF` is common.

The issue you're facing is that the here-document acts like a double-quoted string, 
so the variables and the command substitution in it are expanded when `cat` runs, they're not stored as-is in the resulting file. This is probably not what you want, since you set, e.g. `R_func` in the `batch_x.sh` you're writing, but `${R_func}` would expand to whatever value `R_func` has in the generating script.

You can prevent this, by quoting the here-doc delimiter, i.e. use `cat << 'EOF'` instead. However, this prevents expansion of *all* variables, so you can't have one expanded and the others not without creating the file in parts or using an unquoted delimiter and escaping all but one variable, as in [Uncle Billy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508836/170373).

---

Now, if I understood your idea correctly, you want to create 26 scripts with each letter hard-coded in one of them. The first script you create (`batch_A.sh`) then looks something like this:

```
module load R/3.5.1
R_func="/home/dir/R_func"
....
for AF in ${BASE}/A*.txt_step3; do
   Rscript ${R_func}P_tools.R \
   ...
done
```

Instead, you could create just one script, as below, and the pass the letter to it as a command line argument. The first command line argument is available as `"$1"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
module load R/3.5.1
R_func="/home/dir/R_func"
TREAT="/home/dir/POP"
BASE="/home/dir/base"
OUTPUT="/home/dir/tmp"
letter=$1

for AF in ${BASE}/${letter}*.txt_step3; do
    Rscript "${R_func}P_tools.R" \
    --ptool "${R_func}/P_tools_linux" \
    --group "${AF}" \
    --treat "${TREAT}/pop_exclude24dup" \
    --out "${OUTPUT}/OUT_$(basename "${AF%%_txt_step3}")_noregress" \
    --binary-target F;
done
```

The variable `letter` would now be taken from the command line, so you could run `batch.sh A` to process the `A` files, etc.

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu, great answer and works well!!

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu, I wonder if you could let me know if there's a way to escape the "stored as-is" under the `cat << 'EOF'` circumstance. More specifically, I want `${letter}` in both bash script filename and within the script.

Comment: You mentioned that creating "one" script and passing the letter to it as a command line argument. Could you elaborate more on that? My original thought is to break down files based on alphabets and run in parallel. However, if there's a way to break down the files individually and run scripts in parallel would be even better, I should work on that.

Comment: @Molly_K, I tried to adapt your script to picking `$letter` from the command line. For parallel processing, you could write the script so that it processes just one file, and then run `xargs -P` or use GNU parallel to run a bunch of them at a time.

Comment: There's probably a dozen or so Q&A's about running scripts in parallel here on the site, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169326/170373 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211976/170373 and the search https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=run%20script%20parallel

Comment: @Molly_K a better way to replace some variable in a here-document is to do it the autoconf way: quote the delimiter so you don't have to escape any `$`, and then pipe the heredoc to sed, replacing `@@var@@` with the value of `$var`: `sed <<-'EOT' >out "s|@@var@@|$var|g"; ... lines containing @@var@@ ... EOT` (replace the `|` with a char that doesn't appear in the value of `$var`). But, as ilkkachu has said, it may be that you don't really need to autogenerate any scripts.

Comment: Which reminds me of an earlier question: [Expanding only certain variables inside a heredoc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/505949/170373)